# Gradle Build stuck at app:tranformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

Gradle build getting stuck app:tranformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug. I waited for 1 hr.

This happens when I update my gradle plugin version to 3.4.0 and Gradle version to 5.1.1

I downgraded gradle versions to 3.3.2 and 4.10.1 and it works fine. Check this for gradle versions: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

I want to be able to build with the latest gradle versions. Anyone else face this issue?

Comment: Have you added pro-guard in your app's build.gradle?

Comment: Yes I have added proguard file under buildTypes codeblock.

Comment: According to docs, 3.4.0 doesn't use proguard. "When you build you project using Android Gradle plugin 3.4.0 or higher, the plugin no longer uses ProGuard to perform compile-time code optimization. Instead, the plugin works with the R8 compiler to handle the following compile-time tasks" - Docs. Should I remove proguard then? 

Comment: Try to replace your proguard line to this: proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'  . It worked for me. Hope this may help you.

Comment: Yes thats how I have added Proguard to build.gradle already.

Answer (score 0):

I removed this Proguard line from build.gradle:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

And changed `compileSdkVersion` to 28**